Cloudflare Pages to Handle All Subdomains (Wildcard record for Custom Domain)
I have a static application in Cloudflair Pages.
To connect it to the domain it is required:

Add it to Custom Domain
Then add a CNAME record that points to app-name.pages.dev.

While Cloudflare support an asterisk in CNAME record like *.example.com,
It seems that it is not possible to add a Custom Domain with an asterisk, there is an error "A valid domain must be entered".
Is there a way to configure Cloudflare Pages so that all subdomains of example.com will point to my application?

Unfortunately, as of Apr 2024, you are not allowed to set wildcard subdomain on Cloudflare Pages yet.
Assuming your Cloudflare Page is hosted on example.com, there's 2 alternative workarounds depends on which one you can accept:
Route all wildcard through Cloudflare Workers
As wildcard subdomain is supported in Cloudflare Workers, you can route all requests through your worker that serves the HTML pages (or just proxy to your Cloudflare Page):
export default {
  async fetch(request) {
    const url = new URL(request.url);
    url.hostname = 'example.com';
    return fetch(url.toString(), request);
  },
};

However, keep in mind that there's only 100,000 free requests per day. An additional optimisation would be to serve your static assets through root domain directly instead of proxied through the subdomain.
For example, instead of doing this in your subdomain (eg. hello.example.com):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="/assets/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Do this instead:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://example.com/assets/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Add custom redirection page rules
If you can accept redirection, you can add a page rule that redirects all your requests to subdomains to the root domains.

Create a new proxied (orange cloud) CNAME record to your Cloudflare Page address (eg. https://example.pages.dev). Note that this is just a dummy record so that page rule can take effect.
Go to Rules -> Page Rules and create a new rule
Input the following in the configuration:

URL: *.example.com/*
Setting: Forwarding URL
Status Code: 302 Temporary Redirect
Destination URL: example.com/$1/$2



With this setup, when you go to https://hello.example.com/page?a=1, it will redirect to https://example.com/hello/page?a=1 and you can serve your content there.

I finally crafted a solution but this requires a server with nginx installed.
Here is the nginx configuration

server {
  server_name ~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+).yourwebsite.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://yourwebsite.com/;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For proxy;
    proxy_set_header Host yourwebsite.com;
  }
}

Then in the DNS Records:
Type    Name              Content
--------------------------------------------------------------
CNAME   yourwebsite.com   yourpage.pages.dev
A       *                 <ipaddress of your server with nginx>


The question is about Cloudflare Pages. Your answer is not related to the question.

@Shlomo , Uh it actually answers their question. You can handle "all subdomains" by pointing it to a nginx server that points it back to the original cloudflare page using  proxy_pass. It's just you didn't understand both the OP'question and my answer
